# How to change focusedOption in React-select

Tags: reactjs, forms, drop-down-menu, redux, react-select

Currently I am using react-select 1.2.1 and I am stuck on an issue which requires me to change the focused option from my Select Component but I am not able to find a way around it? 
Thanks in advance.

For eg :

[image]

In the above figure if I press backspace to remove i from the top the focused option still remains to be florida. Instead I want to change the focused option to be the first element when there was no filtering based on 'i'.

Comment: Is there any code you can share that goes with the example? And can you point out where things go wrong or what you are not able to achieve? Thanks

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/7okkxnl2jx Although you can view this but this one uses v2 but the idea here is same that in v1.2.1 whenever I select an option then by default the focus goes to next option. I want to change that behaviour so that I may be able to specify that which option is focused. I mean I should have the power to change the focused option

Comment: When I click on the dropdown box, I hover over an option and click it to add it to the selectbox. Then focus goes to the next one in the list where the mouse hovers above. That's what I see happening. Can you explain again step by step what you are trying to do?

Comment: I have updated the question.Hope that helps.

Comment: That's definitely helpful in what you are trying to do. I can re-create this when I search for ida, as that will select Florida, then when you press backspace twice and "i" remains, Florida will still be selected. But instead you want the top most option to be selected.

Comment: Yes it would be of great help if you could do that but keep in mind I am using react-select v1.2.1 . Actually you would need to mainpulate focusedIndex and focusedOption I guess. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For filtering on the older version, there's more info on that here [Advanced filters](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/tree/v1.x#advanced-filters). I was able to downgrade the version in codesandbox and will try later to see if I can make it work using their docs.

Comment: Hi @TheHumbleGhost, I've searched to V1.3 options and was not able to find an option that lets you do this. Here are the [available options](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/tree/v1.x#select-props). What you could instead to is to post a question on their GitHub if  there is any way to achieve this? I'll update my answer with my findings.

Answer (score 1):

In react-select V1.3. I am under the impression that what you are trying to do is not supported. There are no props on the component that let you control this. Here are the [available props for react-select V1.3](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/tree/v1.x#select-props).

**NOTE: The below only applies to react-select V2, I just read your comment.**

When you are not happy with the default filtering that [react-select](https://react-select.com/home) provides you can add custom filtering. Here's what the docs say about it.

> React-Select exports a createFilter function that returns a
>   filterOptions method. By using this, users can pick and choose bits of
>   the filtration logic to customise, without having to rewrite the logic
>   wholesale.

Here's how you can use it.

```js
// import at the top of your component

import Select, {
  createFilter
} from 'react-select';

// specify what you'd like to use from the filter options
const filterConfig = {
  ignoreCase,
  ignoreAccents,
  trim,
  matchFrom: this.state.matchFromStart ? 'start' : 'any',
};

// render the component
<Select
  defaultValue = { colourOptions[0] }
  isClearable
  isSearchable
  name = "color"
  options = {
    colourOptions
  }
  filterOption = {
    createFilter(filterConfig)
  }
/>
```

It that doesn't give you enough control you can write a custom filter option and pass that as a component prop.

> If you really would like to rewrite the filtration logic from the
>   ground up, simply declare a new filterOptions function to be passed in
>   as a prop to react-select. For details on the shape of the
>   filterOptions prop, please see the proptypes in the api docs

I can copy the code but it's quite a bit. See their [advanced section](https://react-select.com/advanced) in their docs there.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the focus using the ref in version 3.0.8. I am using a functional component. I used onKeyDown to listen for a - z (keyCode 64-91). I then create a Map of the options that start with the same letter as the letter pressed, and cycle through focusing them using the following.

```
reactSelect.current.select.setState({
          focusedOption: foundOptions.get(searchNumber),
        });
```

foundOptions is my Map, and searchNumber is the number of times the letter has been pressed. It's a little hacky, but it works.

I've also done it with version 1.0.0-rc.4 using the ref this.selectRef.focusOption(this.foundOptions.get(this.searchNumber)). Same concept, but there is a function exposed in that version specifically for this.

Comment: Hi Bill,do you have any code-sandbox for it?, i am bit confused in cycling through options, Thanks in Adcance